# Is this schema usable for multi-tenant clients?How to remove multi-cascade paths?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, multi-tenant

I am  newbie to database design. I want to build multi-tenant application that will have the following schema for its data:

```
School(*schoolid*, schoolname, schooltype);

Department(*deptid*,deptname,schoolid);  //schoolid is foreign key

Staff(*staffid*,staffname,contactno,age,courseid, schoolid);  //schoolid,courseid are foreign keys

Course(*courseid*,coursename,coursetype,schoolid);  //schoolid is foreign key

DSC(deptid,staffid,courseid,six,nine); //six,nine are months indicating duration 
of the course to which courseid referes.All ids are foreign keys

SD(staffid,deptid,ten,two,three); //ten,two and three are times at which 
particular staffid is free.All ids are foreign keys
```

The fields within asterisks(*) are primary fields. I want to have 
schoolid in School, Department, Staff, Course tables for security concerns and can't remove it from there. What can be more **optimized structure for multi-tenacy** in this regard? When I use SQL Server 2012 to build this schema, it **gives multi-cascade cycles error. **.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you post your actual DDL?  The cascade error can only occur if you are cascading updates.  I tend not to do that in my designs, but in your case, if that's a feature you actually want to use, then you cannot cascade in a way which causes ambiguity or cycles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-tenancy" in this context? Partitioning the data by school?

Comment: @JonSeigel: Different schools will be our clients and they will use this shared data.

Comment: Depending on who your clients are, you'll want to be very careful about data partitioning and security -- in some instances, districts (also known as school boards) require (possibly by law) their data to be completely isolated from everyone else. Sometimes a database boundary is okay, sometimes that's not enough. Again, be very, *very* careful with this, or you'll end up back at the design phase at a late stage in the project. (FYI: I work in this field.)

Comment: @JonSeigel I am well aware of these issues..Thanks for reminding me those things again...

Answer (score 1):

To achieve multi-tennancy you should limit the number of relationships you have to the factor that determines the tennant.

For example, each of `Course`, `Department` and `Staff` have a foreign key to `School`.  However, these child tables are also interrelated.  Is it necessary for `Staff` to have a `schoolid`?  You can get to the school a staff member works for by following the foreign key to `Course`.

Similarly, you have grand-child tables (`SD` and `DSC`) which are relating tables in curious ways.  What has *"months indicating duration of the course"* to do with which staff member is teaching the course?  Is it really necessary for `DSC` to relate to `Staff`?  Also, you appear to have repeating groups defined in your `SD` and `SDC` tables.  I believe you may have a normalization issue.

By over-relating tables you create cascade cycles.  Consider the following ERD as an alternative:

[image: ERD]

Here there is only one potential cycle to be concerned with, instead of the several that are in your current model.  Fewer potential cycles means less extra work that might need to be done with triggers instead of declarative referential constraints.  This keeps your system simpler and more maintainable.